# C++ OpenGL LNK2001 when header is included

Tags: c++, opengl, lnk2001

I am getting 28

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

messages. I know for a fact, for example, that

```
glBindVertexArray
```

is in _int_gl_exts.h, and sure enough I am including it.

```
#include <glload\_int_gl_exts.h>
```

I don't know if this is a problem, but there are three underscore characters in my error message

```
symbol ___gleBindVertexArray
```

Whereas in the file, there is only two underscores before it. This is the exact line inside the include file

```
extern PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYPROC __gleBindVertexArray;
#define glBindVertexArray __gleBindVertexArray
```

I am pulling much of my stuff directly from a tutorial, and even when my includes and functions are the same, I still have problems. I'll post full code if necessary, but I am out of ideas after about 2 days stuck here.

EDIT: I do in fact have both

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
```

as well as I tried changing the Project Properties in Linker to add this to additional libraries.

My entire code is as follows. I understand there's a lot of other stuff that needs changed, but this is what I'm trying to get past first.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string.h>
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>
#include <glutil/Shader.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "framework.h"
#include "directories.h"
#include <glload/_int_gl_exts.h>

#ifdef LOAD_X11
#define APIENTRY
#endif

namespace Framework
{
GLuint LoadShader(GLenum eShaderType, const std::string &strShaderFilename)
{
    std::string strFilename = FindFileOrThrow(strShaderFilename);
    std::ifstream shaderFile(strFilename.c_str());
    std::stringstream shaderData;
    shaderData << shaderFile.rdbuf();
    shaderFile.close();

    try
    {
        return glutil::CompileShader(eShaderType, shaderData.str());
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        throw;
    }
}

GLuint CreateProgram(const std::vector<GLuint> &shaderList)
{
    try
    {
        GLuint prog = glutil::LinkProgram(shaderList);
        std::for_each(shaderList.begin(), shaderList.end(), glDeleteShader);
        return prog;
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        std::for_each(shaderList.begin(), shaderList.end(), glDeleteShader);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        throw;
    }
}

float DegToRad(float fAngDeg)
{
    const float fDegToRad = 3.14159f * 2.0f / 360.0f;
    return fAngDeg * fDegToRad;
}

std::string FindFileOrThrow( const std::string &strBasename )
{
    std::string strFilename = LOCAL_FILE_DIR + strBasename;
    std::ifstream testFile(strFilename.c_str());
    if(testFile.is_open())
        return strFilename;


    strFilename = GLOBAL_FILE_DIR + strBasename;
    testFile.open(strFilename.c_str());
    if(testFile.is_open())
        return strFilename;

    throw std::runtime_error("Could not find the file " + strBasename);
}
}


void init();
void display();
void reshape(int w, int h);
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

unsigned int defaults(unsigned int displayMode, int &width, int &height);

void APIENTRY DebugFunc(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length,
           const GLchar* message, GLvoid* userParam)
{
std::string srcName;
switch(source)
{
case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API_ARB: srcName = "API"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM_ARB: srcName = "Window System"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER_ARB: srcName = "Shader Compiler"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY_ARB: srcName = "Third Party"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION_ARB: srcName = "Application"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER_ARB: srcName = "Other"; break;
}

std::string errorType;
switch(type)
{
case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR_ARB: errorType = "Error"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR_ARB: errorType = "Deprecated Functionality"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR_ARB: errorType = "Undefined Behavior"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY_ARB: errorType = "Portability"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_ARB: errorType = "Performance"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER_ARB: errorType = "Other"; break;
}

std::string typeSeverity;
switch(severity)
{
case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH_ARB: typeSeverity = "High"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM_ARB: typeSeverity = "Medium"; break;
case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW_ARB: typeSeverity = "Low"; break;
}

printf("%s from %s,\t%s priority\nMessage: %s\n",
    errorType.c_str(), srcName.c_str(), typeSeverity.c_str(), message);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);

int width = 500;
int height = 500;
unsigned int displayMode = GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL;
displayMode = defaults(displayMode, width, height);

glutInitDisplayMode (displayMode);
glutInitContextVersion (3, 3);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef DEBUG
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_DEBUG);
#endif
glutInitWindowSize (width, height); 
glutInitWindowPosition (300, 200);
int window = glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

glload::LoadFunctions();

glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);

if(!glload::IsVersionGEQ(3, 3))
{
    printf("Your OpenGL version is %i, %i. You must have at least OpenGL 3.3 to run this tutorial.\n",
        glload::GetMajorVersion(), glload::GetMinorVersion());
    glutDestroyWindow(window);
    return 0;
}

if(glext_ARB_debug_output)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
    glDebugMessageCallbackARB(DebugFunc, (void*)15);
}

init();

glutDisplayFunc(display); 
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <glload\_int_gl_exts.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glload\_int_gl_1_5.h>
#include <glload\_int_gl_1_1_rem_3_1.h>
#include "../../framework/framework.h"

#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

GLuint theProgram;
GLuint elapsedTimeUniform;

void InitializeProgram()
{
std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;

shaderList.push_back(Framework::LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "calcOffset.vert"));
shaderList.push_back(Framework::LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "calcColor.frag"));

theProgram = Framework::CreateProgram(shaderList);

elapsedTimeUniform = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "time");

GLuint loopDurationUnf = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "loopDuration");
GLuint fragLoopDurUnf = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "fragLoopDuration");


glUseProgram(theProgram);
glUniform1f(loopDurationUnf, 5.0f);
glUniform1f(fragLoopDurUnf, 10.0f);
glUseProgram(0);
}

const float vertexPositions[] = {
0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

GLuint positionBufferObject;
GLuint vao;

void createCube() {
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glLineWidth(99.0);

  glColor3f(   1.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

  glVertex3f(  0.5,0.5,0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,0.5,-0.5 );

  glVertex3f( 0.5,0.5,-0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,0.5,-0.5 );

  glVertex3f( -0.5,0.5,-0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,0.5,0.5 );

  glVertex3f( -0.5,0.5,0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,0.5,0.5 );

  glVertex3f(  0.5,-0.5,0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,-0.5,-0.5 );

  glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 );

  glVertex3f( -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,-0.5,0.5 );

  glVertex3f( -0.5,-0.5,0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,0.5 );

  glVertex3f( 0.5,0.5,0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,0.5 );

  glVertex3f( -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,0.5,-0.5 );

  glVertex3f( 0.5,0.5,-0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 );

  glVertex3f( -0.5,0.5,0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,-0.5,0.5 );

  glEnd();
}

void InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

//Called after the window and OpenGL are initialized. Called exactly once, before the main loop.
void init()
{
InitializeProgram();
InitializeVertexBuffer();

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
}

//Called to update the display.
//You should call glutSwapBuffers after all of your rendering to display what you rendered.
//If you need continuous updates of the screen, call glutPostRedisplay() at the end of the function.
void display()
{
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(theProgram);

glUniform1f(elapsedTimeUniform, glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0f);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);


createCube();
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glutSolidSphere(0.04,10,10);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glUseProgram(0);

glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}

    //Called whenever the window is resized. The new window size is given, in pixels.
    //This is an opportunity to call glViewport or glScissor to keep up with the change in size.
void reshape (int w, int h)
{
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
}

//Called whenever a key on the keyboard was pressed.
//The key is given by the ''key'' parameter, which is in ASCII.
//It's often a good idea to have the escape key (ASCII value 27) call glutLeaveMainLoop() to 
//exit the program.
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key)
{
case 27:
    glutLeaveMainLoop();
    return;
}
}


unsigned int defaults(unsigned int displayMode, int &width, int &height) {return displayMode;}
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if you actually stated [what library you were trying to link to](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html). The only reason I know which one it is is because I recognize my own work ;)

In any case, [the documentation makes it clear what library you should link to](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_use.html#page_use_native). If you're using the Premake4 build system, then you should just have `UseLibs {"glload"}` in your `premake4.lua` project. If you're using something else, then you need to manually link to `glloadD` or `glload` in debug and release respectively. On Windows, you need a .lib suffix; on Linux, you would use `libglloadD` and such.

Whether you link with a pragma or use the project settings is irrelevant.

Comment: I had included all the libraries, but I forgot about needing both debug and release versions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Including the declarations is one thing; their definitions are another.

You must *link* against the OpenGL library when you build your executable.

Follow the instructions in your OpenGL book or reference, but typically you'll pass something like `-lopengl32` to your build command; it looks like you might be using Visual Studio, which handles the specific build command for you, in which case you should add the OpenGL libraries to your project properties [or use `#pragma`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055320/560648):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't link the opengl lib file.

In your compiler settings, add to the list of included libraries "opengl32.lib".

Comment: It's misleading to talk about "include"ing libraries.

Comment: I have both #pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib"), as well as changed the project properties under Linker to include this. no avail

Comment: Where did i say to include the library? ;)