# Cant compile an example from opengl redbook

Tags: c++, opengl, linker

so i have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vgl.h>
#include <LoadShaders.h>
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };
GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];
const GLuint NumVertices = 6;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// init
//
void
    init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        { -0.90, -0.90 }, // Triangle 1
        { 0.85, -0.90 },
        { -0.90, 0.85 },
        { 0.90, -0.85 }, // Triangle 2
        { 0.90, 0.90 },
        { -0.85, 0.90 }
    };
    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),
        vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
        { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };
    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// display
//
void
    display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
    glFlush();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// main
//
int
    main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    if (glewInit()) {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

When i run it i get:

```
Warning 23  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\LINK    RedBook
Warning 24  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)    RedBook
Error   6   error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)    c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0dat.obj) RedBook
Error   21  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(winxfltr.obj)    RedBook
Error   20  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(mlock.obj)   RedBook
Error   19  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)   c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(mlock.obj)   RedBook
Error   8   error LNK2005: __ldused already defined in a previous module    c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(fpinit.obj)  RedBook
Error   1   error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(invarg.obj)  RedBook
Error   5   error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0dat.obj) RedBook
Error   7   error LNK2005: __fltused already defined in a previous module   c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(fpinit.obj)  RedBook
Error   4   error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)   c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0dat.obj) RedBook
Error   22  error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(wsetloca.obj)    RedBook
Error   3   error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0dat.obj) RedBook
Error   9   error LNK2005: __calloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crtheap.obj) RedBook
Error   2   error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0dat.obj) RedBook
Error   15  error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0init.obj)    RedBook
Error   14  error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0init.obj)    RedBook
Error   17  error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0init.obj)    RedBook
Error   16  error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(crt0init.obj)    RedBook
Error   18  error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(errmode.obj) RedBook
Error   12  error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(winapisupp.obj)  RedBook
Error   11  error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)   c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(winapisupp.obj)  RedBook
Error   10  error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)    c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(winapisupp.obj)  RedBook
Error   13  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)   c:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\RedBook\libcmt.lib(hooks.obj)   RedBook
Error   25  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   c:\users\naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RedBook\Debug\RedBook.exe   1   1   RedBook
```

I followed what @Mario said here:
[error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LoadShaders referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886087/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-loadshaders-referenced-in-function-v)

And I have this on my *Linker Additional Dependencies*:

```
opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;
```

When I add *glut32.lib* I get an error that it could not be opened, so I downloaded it and added it to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib* But i still get the same error.

The files for the example's and all the lib and stuff can be found here: [link](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/Code/oglpg-8th-edition.zip)

EDIT : And my Runtime Library on Code Generation is : *Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)*

Comment: Did you ever get this example to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of GLUT you're using is built against a different version/configuration of the runtime library. I suggest you install [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) (the original GLUT is long-dead), and make sure you build freeglut with the same configuration as you use for your application.

Comment: I am using freeglut now and I have these errors:http://pastebin.com/7Gn0jiJL

EDIT : Now the error is just that it cant open _freeglut32.lib_ :\ ( I have added _freeglut32.lib_ to the linker)

Comment: It sounds like the path to freeglut32.lib isn't in your project's library search path.

Comment: You are right my bad, its _freeglut.lib_, now my errors are:http://pastebin.com/cuftMtxv
 Thanks!

Comment: Again, you need to make sure *the configurations are the same*. Here it looks like one is being built in release mode and the other is being built in debug mode. It needs to be *the same runtime*.

Comment: Any of the Runtime that i change it into wont work, what should i do?