# Debug issue for OpenGL while using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I have trouble with debugging OpenGL code in Visual Studio 2012

```
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LoadShaders referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)  C:\Users\New User\Documents\OpenGl\Lesson1_1test\Lesson1_1test\triangles.obj    Lesson1_1test
```

here is my code and it from book called `OpenGL Programming Guide: The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, Version 4.3 (8th Edition)`

```
//
//
// triangles.cpp
//
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs {Triangles, NumVAOs};
enum Buffer_IDs {ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers};
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0};

GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint NumVertices = 6;

//--init

void 
init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);

    GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        {-0.90, -0.90},
        {0.85, -0.90},
        {-0.90, 0.85},
        {0.90, -0.85},
        {0.90, 0.90},
        {-8.50, 0.90}
    };

    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ShaderInfo shaders[] = {{GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert"}, { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag"},{ GL_NONE, NULL}};

    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

//Display

void 
display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);

    glFlush();
}


//main

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(512,512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4,3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    if(glewInit()) {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Check this SO link  "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LoadShaders..."- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886087/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-loadshaders-referenced-in-function-v

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886087/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-loadshaders-referenced-in-function-v

Comment: have you added those files to your project? "loadshaders" and "vgl"

Comment: yes i already added "loadshaders" and "vgl" too compile is not issue but debugging is error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the opengl directories are added to your lookup path directories.  In VS2010 the dialog looks like this:
[image: Add directories to lookup paths]

In VS2012 the dialog looks like this:
[image: Add directories to lookup paths]

In both you can get to them by going to project properties >> VC++ Directories

Add locations based on the following:

- `Bin` directory (contains dll files for example) add to `executable directories`
- `include` directory (containing .h files) add to `include directories`
- `library` directory (containing .lib files) add to `library directories`
- `source` directory (containing .cpp files) add to `source directories`

`reference` and `exclude` directories you can leave alone unless you have an explicit need to alter them.

*Hope this helps, but let me know if you need more info!:)*

Comment: yeah thank you for quality detail explain however...i just realize this book might not for window......coz of i can't find .dll or .lib for window os. that is biggest problem is I have not .dll or file file. or i rather it is problem from Visual Studio 2012? I only see freeglut_static.lib, freeglut_static.lib and freeglut_vs2010s.lib etc Now I will trying visual studio 2010 now.

Comment: you might not need to set all the paths, just the ones you need, so if you are using static libraries (.lib files) you may not need a dll path :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some lib file to the linker. It is probably in some project setup dialog.